# On a strictly increasing continuous subadditive function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, continuity

Consider a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow[0,\infty)$ which is strictly increasing, subadditive and $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$. For $\alpha<1$, we have
$$f(x)\leq\alpha f(y)\qquad\implies x\leq\alpha^\prime y,\qquad \text{for some } \alpha^\prime<1. $$

Numerical calculations (using `Sagemath`) suggests that $\alpha^\prime\leq\alpha$, however I am unable to show it. I'd be delighted if someone can help me out.

If my conjecture is wrong, under what minimum additional condition would it hold?

Comment: I am not familiar with sub-additive functions but your assertion that $\alpha'\leq \alpha$ is equivalent to the inequality $\alpha f(y)\leq f(\alpha y)$.

Comment: Is the existence of $\alpha'$ part of the hypothesis or the conclusion? If the latter, it's not at all clear to me...

Comment: Since $f$ is strictly increasing, $f(x)\leq \alpha f(y)$ implies $x<y$ and so, $x\leq \alpha^\prime$ for some $\alpha^\prime<1$. I need to show $\alpha^\prime\leq\alpha$.

Comment: ok - I assumed you meant that $\alpha'$ was independent of $x$ and $y$.